# why does db.query(Item).all().filter(Item.is_active == True) fail with error AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'filter'

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, fastapi

As the title says, adding a .filter after the db.query(Item).all() fails with AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'filter'.

```
    items = db.query(Item).all().filter(Item.is_active == True)
    return items
```

But if i remove the .filter it works but i really want to filter.

```
def list_items(db : Session):
    items = db.query(Item).all()
    return items
```

Here is the route:

```
@router.get("/all", response_model=List[ShowItem])
def read_items(db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
    items = list_items(db=db)
    return items
```

Here is the class:

```
class Item(BaseModel):
    name: str
    price: int

    class Config():
        orm_mode = True
```

Here is the Table DB Model:

```
class Item(Base):
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    name = Column(String, nullable=False)
    price = (Column(Integer, nullable=False))
    is_active = Column(Boolean(), default=True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.all()` method returns list which does not have `filter` method, you need to 1st use `filter` then `all` that is replace

```
items = db.query(Item).all().filter(Item.is_active == True)
```

using

```
items = db.query(Item).filter(Item.is_active == True).all()
```

Comment: Thanks so much. This is the right answer. The tutorial i was using used .all before .filter.